# Getting tag article count

Tags: python, django

I want to get each tag's article count from taggitItem table;
I have written the following but it doesn't work correctly.

```
article_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Article)
articles = TaggedItem.objects.filter(content_type = article_content_type).annotate(count = Count('tag'))
```

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

```
article_count = TaggedItem.objects.filter(content_type = article_content_type).count()
```

Perhaps it is even better not to use the TaggedItem class, but do it via the Article class.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please, if you downvote, help our new users to improve their answers.

Comment: This gives the total number of tags used throughout the articles, i.e. a single number. Question asked for "each tag's article count".